# how to split the datetime column into date and time and compare individually

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a visit table

with columns

```
            member_id
           visit_id
           visit_logout_datetime(values like this... '
```

now i need to compare the visit_logout_datetime with today date time property...

here is two conditions

1) i need to `compare the today date with date` coming from this field visit_logout_datetime

// here i want to do something....

2) i need to compare the  `present time with the time in this field`  visit_logout_datetime

i want to compare individually ..

how can i do that ..

would any one pls help on this....

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
mysql> select cast('2011-10-24 15:20:10' as date);
+-------------------------------------+
| cast('2011-10-24 15:20:10' as date) |
+-------------------------------------+
| 2011-10-24                          |
+-------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select cast('2011-10-24 15:20:10' as time);
+-------------------------------------+
| cast('2011-10-24 15:20:10' as time) |
+-------------------------------------+
| 15:20:10                            |
+-------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the MySQL function [DATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date) to extract the date component, and similarly [TIME](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_time) to obtain that part.